# iPad persistent identifier like serial number without use of I/O Kit

Tags: ios, ipad, iokit, serial-number

For now we use **I/O Kit** for getting device **serial number**, as it won't change after resetting device etc. Serial number is used for **identifying iPad on server side**. Use of **I/O Kit blocks Simulator** though.

If we wanted to add UI tests in simulator, we would need to stop using I/O Kit, but we **still need to have a possibility to identify real devices** the way, that identifier won't ever change.

I was looking at [identifierForVendor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#jumpTo_7) in iOS Dev Library, but it would changes after resetting the device.

**To sum up, we need a way to get serial number, or equivalent without use of I/O Kit.**

Thanks!

Comment: No. For privacy reasons there is no such thing anymore. (And before anyone says MAC-Adress, [this option will go away soon too](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/14/ios-7-eliminates-mac-address-as-tracking-option-signaling-final-push-towards-apples-own-ad-identifier-technology/)). Also IOKit is a private framework and your app won't make it to the app store if you use it.

Comment: Thanks,

We don't use official app store (we have some kind of our enterprise one); Is there a way then to use I/O Kit only when compiling among iOS device, and don't when using Simulator? What should we do with iOS7 to maintain per-device identification?